# What is the fastest way to perform below operation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Assuming an array *A* of integers of size *m* and *n* to be some random number.

What is the fastest way to calculate the following,

`A[i]%n + A[i+1]%n + ----A[m]%n`

One way is to directly perform the operation. Is there a way we can calculate it using Modular arithmatics?

Comment: I think that you can apply the euclidean algorithm $A_k=n\cdot q_k+r_k$

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran You mean Extended Euclidean algorithm? I read it and didn't understand how that theorem can solve this problem.

Comment: @Peter It wouldn't give the right result if the sum of the remainders is larger than $n$.